# jQuery Booklet plugin using gotopage method

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. I am using the booklet plugin. I need to access the gotopage method, but can't seem to get it work. Below is the code for this method, just not sure how to use it. I want to be able to select either a hyperlink or a button to go to another page.

```
$('#custom-goto').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();         
   $('#mybook').booklet("gotopage", "end");
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Tony, welcome to SO. In order to help others to help you please to a moment and look into this to improve your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by changing all the javascript libraries to their latests version.

Another possible cause is that you tried to edit an example provided by the internet and that example had established configurations that prevent the default behavior of gotopage.